# Abort() has been called Error while debugging C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

i am trying to implement simple binaryHeap and this part is a percolateDown part however when it comes to else part, it crashes and gives me abort() error , it happens in after i continue "}else{" line. I dont understand the problem and i am a bit new in C++.

```
void BinaryHeap::percolateDown(int hole) {

    int leftChild = hole * 2;

    if (leftChild>size){
        //DO NOTHING AND ROLLS BACK IN RECURSION
    }else{
        int minIndex = hole;
        if (heap[minIndex] > heap[2 * hole]){
            minIndex = 2 * hole;
        }
        if (heap[minIndex] > heap[2 * hole + 1]){
            minIndex = 2 * hole + 1;
        }
        swap(hole, minIndex);
        percolateDown(minIndex);
    }

}
```

Comment: The most likely cause is that you are accessing `heap` out of bounds. Before you access `heap`, print the indices and make sure that they are within the valid range.

Comment: Thank you i am trying it now